# How to remove TabsPage in Ionic 3 programmatically?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to remove some pages in the navstack of Ionic3 because when I use the QR plugin the tabs page overlaps the camera.

Tried so far with no success:

```
this.navCtrl.popAll();
this.navCtrl.push(QrPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can only close the latest page open in the nav-stack
with this.navCtrl.pop() as you know

```
goBack(){
     this.navCtrl.pop();
  }
```

If you want to close all use

```
nav.popToRoot()
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the remove function:

```
let currentIndex = this.navController.getActive().index;
this.navController.push(DestinationPage).then(() => {
    this.navController.remove(currentIndex);
});
```

Hope it works!